# How to find the logged in user in Sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts

I have developed a "web part" that has to be deployed on a Sharepoint server. I need the username of the user, who has logged in the sharepoint server within the web part.

How do I get that username?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey all, i got the answer for my question Hope this will work for you all...
First add a reference to the MicrosoftSharepoint.dll file in your web part.
then write 
using  Microsoft.SharePoint;

```
            string username;
            string sspURL = "URL where Sharepoint is deployed";

            SPSite site = new SPSite(sspURL);

            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

            SPUser user = web.CurrentUser;

            username = user.LoginName;

            site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
```

Yours,
Jigar <3

Answer (score 29):

Following worked for me:

```
SPWeb theSite = SPControl.GetContextWeb(Context);
SPUser theUser = theSite.CurrentUser;
string strUserName = theUser.LoginName;
```

and check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/acc74f5e-9f28-4a94-b041-27f4d932fa38) out.

Comment: Or much better: `string strUserName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;`

Answer (score 13):

You can use:

```
SPWeb web = SPControl.GetContextWeb(this.Context);
string userName = web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
```

or

```
string userName = this.Context.User.Identity.Name;
```

And you should check `this.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` as well to ensure there is a user logged in before trying to extract the username.

Comment: I prefer the second option.  Catch for me was with internal mapping to AD, it has a bunch of garbage preceeders like `0#.w|domain\username`.  But otherwise the 2nd implementation worked great for me.

Comment: @GoldBishop, you can get the username from the claims representation with the following code: SPClaimProviderManager mgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
if (mgr != null)
{
    userName = mgr.DecodeClaim(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName).Value;
}

Comment: Interesting, ill run it through some tests and see how it interprets.  But otherwise i just did `userid = this.Context.User.Identity.Name; userid = userid.Substring( userid.IndexOf( '|' ) + 1 );` and was able to seperate the garbage from what i needed for the information.

Comment: Which works, but it's not garbage. It's a claims identifier and Welcome to the new world of identities :)

Comment: depends on how you see it, for what i need the information for its garbage.  i realize the information is descriptive but it is overhead text i dont need ;)

Answer (score 3):

`SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser`

Answer (score 1):

//don't forget to add System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement as reference and using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

```
    PrincipalContext insPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain","DC=MyDomain,DC=com");
    UserPrincipal insUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(insPrincipalContext);
    insUserPrincipal.Name = "*";
    PrincipalSearcher insPrincipalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
    insPrincipalSearcher.QueryFilter = insUserPrincipal;
    PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = insPrincipalSearcher.FindAll();
    foreach (Principal p in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get current logged user ID by **_spPageContextInfo** property.

```
 _spPageContextInfo.userId
```

You will get current user's ID by **_spPageContextInfo**. Try this may help you.