# How to get the name or IP of current web server in Sharepoint using C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, webserver

I am trying to get the server name or IP in a SharePoint farm I am accessing. we have a load balance and two web front ends so it is confusing for the debug to find out which server is being accessed. 
Is there a way we can find out the current WFE in SharePoint being accessed using C# code. I am not finding the correct function.
Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Does System.Environment.MachineName not work in the context of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Use the SPuser class

```
SPUser currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
```

You can find some usefull information here

[How to find the logged in user in Sharepoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423268/how-to-find-the-logged-in-user-in-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Dns.GetHostAddresses` method ([MSDN - Dns.GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx)) and pass in an empty string for the host name which will return the ip of the local host. Add `using System.Net;` then try:

```
IPAddress[] ips;

ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses("");    

foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
{
    // Code to display IP address
}
```