# Import user credentials via WebPart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I would like to import user credentials via WebPart. For example WebPart is open by "domain/jack.strong" and I need this information in my WebPart. How to do it?

Using Spmetal and generate .cs ???

http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/rhutton/archive/2013/01/08/using-spmetal-to-generate-sharepoint-2013-linq-classes.aspx

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423268/how-to-find-the-logged-in-user-in-sharepoint